# Есть проблема с \t

Tags: c#

```
using System;

class Trigon
{
    static void Main()
    {
        for (double theta = 0.1; theta <= 1.0; theta = theta + 0.1)
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("Синус {0:F2} равен {1:F2}\t Косинус {0:F2} равен {2:F2} Тангенс {0:F2} равен {3:F2}", theta, Math.Sin(theta), Math.Cos(theta), Math.Tan(theta));
        }
    }
}
```

Здравствуйте, уважаемые.С помощью ответов из предыдущего вопроса я немного усовершенствовал свой код. :) Убрал лишние слова и `Console.WriteLine()` И никаких новых `for()`! :D Получил симпатичные столбцы.Но опять возникла проблема(знаю я надоел, но мне больше некому обратиться. :( Есть ли вы считаете меня тупым можете писать ссылки на нужный материал я прочитаю!!!).В коде использую `\t` (вроде это таб).На `{1:F2}\t` все красиво и нормально, но когда пишу `\t` после `{2:F2}` расстояние между значением "Косинуса" и словом "Тангенс"  2 раза больше(вроде, это на глаз).Увеличивается расстояние и между строками.В чем проблема(почему меня это так волнует?Я Перфекционист! :D )?
Можно было добавить пробелы и вручную но я считаю что это тоже нужно доверить машине. xD Или может есть другие специальные команды чтобы ставить пробелы(пример: `\p5` (это 5 пробелов.Значение которое можно изменять))?

Comment: вы в курсе что [табуляция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) это не одно и то же что несколько пробелов, и она привязана к определенным позициям в строке, а не относительно символа после которого она идет?

Comment: @teran Уже в курсе!Спасибо большое. :) Я взял это из другого кода.И нашел очень мало информации(я про \t).Открыл гугл, написал таб.На первой странице было написано про 8 пробелов, закрыл гугл. :D Прочитаю побольше. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблему с `\t` объяснил @Umed в своём ответе, а я расскажу, как с этим бороться.

Если вам нужно вставить фиксированное число пробелов, вы можете использовать просто форматирование с указанием желаемой ширины поля вывода. Например, так:

```
Console.WriteLine("Синус {0:F2} равен {1:F2}{4,20}Косинус {0:F2} равен {2:F2} Тангенс {0:F2} равен {3:F2}", theta, Math.Sin(theta), Math.Cos(theta), Math.Tan(theta), null);
```

Я добавил фиктивный последний аргумент `null`, который выводится после синуса в поле шириной в 20 символов.

Если вы используете C# 6, можно писать и проще:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Синус {theta:F2} равен {Math.Sin(theta):F2}{' ',20}Косинус {theta:F2} равен {Math.Cos(theta):F2} Тангенс {Math.Cos(theta):F2} равен {Math.Tan(theta):F2}");
```

Comment: Ну с интерполяцией выходит больше букв чем без нее.Каждый раз надо писать "theta".Ваш ответ самый лучший(имхо). :) Зеленую стрелочку вам. :D

Comment: Вы выше использовали {' ',20}, а я в коде написал {"",4} , ( " ) вместо ( ' ).В чем разница?Я даже пробел не поставил между кавычками...И все работает.

Comment: @Tobi: Разницы нет, в любом случае вы дополняете пустую строку или там пробел другими пробелами до 20 символов. То есть получается в итоге 20 пробелов.

Answer (score 2):

`\t` выравнивает слова по табуляции добавляя недостающие пробелы, но когда слова выравнены по табам и Вы пишите `\t`, то добавляете 8 (или сколько у Вас таб?) пробельных символов дополнительно.

Пример (один таб - 8 символов, один символ пробела заменён на `-|`, чтобы проще было считать):

> 1234 **\t** 9

превратится в:

> 1234 **-|-|-|** 9

То есть добавилось 3 символа и текст, слева от `\t`, выровнялся до недостающей табуляции.

Другой пример (здесь уже есть два знака пробела):

> 123456-|-| **\t** 9

Превратится в:

> 12345-|-| **-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|** 9

Слева от знака `\t` уже 8 символов и если мы после них напишем `\t`, то добавим дополнительный таб (то есть 8 символов, так как текст уже был выровнен):

Comment: Спасибо большое.А как быть с пробелами?Нету таких команд?)Если например мне захочется добавить в текст 1000 пробелов то это надо делать вручную?Или писать дополнителтный код для такой ерунды? :/

Comment: @Tobi, для тысячи пробелов, увы, придётся написать немного кода самому)